# CakePHP getting warning failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: docker, cakephp

In docker file I have given below setting

```
RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync \
 && install-php-extensions bz2 \
        mbstring\
        gettext \
        intl \
        exif \
        pdo_mysql
```

But I getting this warning

```
SplFileInfo::openFile(/var/www/html/tmp/cache/models/myapp_cake_model_default_products): failed to open stream: Permission denied [CORE/src/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 387]
```

How can I give a permission in docker container to prevent this warning ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem after add 'mask' => 0666 in app/cache

```
'Cache' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => FileEngine::class,
            'path' => CACHE,
            'url' => env('CACHE_DEFAULT_URL', null),
            'mask' => 0666,
        ],
```